# Passing date in Agenda using variable

Tags: node.js, agenda

suppose i got date as x=12 y=45 and i want to perform a task at 12:45 daily using agenda node js. So my question is ,
how to pass date from js variable to `Agenda.schedule("at x:y",'doSometask')`

Answer (score 0):

simple use this.just concatenate the variable in string.

```
    var x=12;
    var y=45;
    a = "at "+x+":"+y;
    Agenda.schedule(a,'doSometask')
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer! What if i got that time value from mongo db and if i change the value from my mongodb collection ! will the task timing change automatically or not ?

Comment: yes the time change change automatically if you used the data coming from mongo like the value of x and y coming from mongo. if answer helps you then upvote.

Comment: `var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda();

agenda.database('192.168.2.152:27017/agenda-test', 'agendaJobs');

   var x=11;
    var y=59;
    a = "at "+x+":"+y;

agenda.define('init', function (job,done) {
 
   console.log("INIT AGENDA"); 
done();
});
   
agenda.on('ready', function () {

    console.log("Agenda ready to start");
agenda.schedule(a,'init');
agenda.start();
});`

Comment: can you use find or findOne to find the value of x and y from db. you can also refer to this https://github.com/shekhartyagi26/TodoApp/blob/master/routes/index.js

Comment: you can also use find value from database like this database_name.findOne({id:req.body.id}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({status: 0, message: err});
            }
            if (!user) {
                res.json({status: 0, msg: "not found"});
            }
            res.json(user);
        })

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x=14;
    var y=23;
var z=x-2;
    a = "at "+z+":"+y;

agenda.define('init', function (job) {

   console.log("INIT AGENDA"); 
//job.schedule(a);
//job.save();

});

agenda.on('ready', function () {

    console.log("Agenda ready to start");
agenda.schedule(a,'init');
agenda.start();
});
```

This worked for me !!